# Checking the axis of array for zero values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know that `numpy.all()` checks if all elements of an array are non-zero other wise (along specified axis). So,

```
A = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
A
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])

A.all(axis=0)
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Suppose I'm interested in checking the last elements of the array only, not whole axis, like:

```
B = np.array([[[ 1,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting from `B`?

Comment: Are you interested in just the last row of the last matrix always or is there a more general arrangement you are interested in detecting?

Comment: @JosephGlover I am interested in the last `n rows` say last 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to just use the `-1` index (negative indices index backwards from the end of the sequence like object).

```py
B = np.array([[[ 1,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [0, 0, 0]]])

print(B[-1, -1])
print(np.any(B[-1, -1]))
print(np.all(B[-1, -1]))
```

Gives

```
[0 0 0]
False
False
```

From there you can use whatever method you want to determine truthiness or falsiness.

Comment: It's better do `B[-1,-1]` than `B[-1][-1]`.

Comment: I would like to check the last `n rows`. For example, checking the last 5-rows.

Comment: Do you mean the last `n` rows from the last matrix or the last row in each of the last `n` matrices?

Comment: last `n rows`from each of the last `n matrices`